# Having an issue with the "this" modifier

Tags: c#, this

I have this method in City class. It should create a new city based on the object which the method is applied to:

```
 public City newCity(string newCityName, int dX, int dY)
    {
        City c=new City(this); //based on a constructor : City(City c){}

        c.CityName=newCityName;
        c.NoOfNeighborhoods=1;
        c.NumOfResidents=0;
        c.CityCenter.Move(dX,dY);

        return c;
    }
```

CityCenter is of type "Point" which has two fields - x,y.
the Move method in Point class is ment to change the CityCenter location. It looks like this:

```
 public void Move(int dX, int dY)
    {
        this.X = x + dX;
        this.Y = y + dY;
    }
```

What happens is that the new object,c and the existing City object are both changed. I think that "this" modifier works on the existing object too...

How can I take advantage of the Move method without causing this behavior?
Note: this is a closed API, so I can only add private methods to the project.

Comment: It might help to post the code in `City(City c){}`

Comment: Can you post the code of the `City(City c)` constructor? I suspect it creates a shallow copy so the `CityCenter` property refers to the same `Point` instance.

Comment: Is there a reason why Point isn't a Structure instead of a class?  Is there a reason why Point isn't an existing structure that is already provided in the .NET framework?

Comment: here is the constructor:

        public City(City c)
            : this(c.cityName,
                   c.cityCenter,
                   c.centralStation,
                   c.numOfResidents,
                   c.noOfNeighborhoods)
        {
        }

Comment: @user344246: Yes, then indeed, both of your cities are ending up with the same `CityCenter` object. There's your problem.

Comment: As a side note, the Move method above will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that Point is a class, so you are sharing the reference to the same instance of the point. You will need to create a new instance of the Point and assign that to the new City.CityCenter

Answer (score 4):

I suspect `City c=new City(this);` is creating a *shallow* clone of the current City which means they both share the same Point object (could only be true if Point is a class and not a struct).

Can you do `City c=new City();` instead?

Comment: Depending on if that works you might also be needing to create a new CityCenter for you new City...  c.CityCenter = new CityCenter();

Answer (score 2):

The problem is (almost certainly) that both cities have a reference to the same `Point` object. When you change the object, that change is seen through both references. Options:

- Create a new Point object when you clone the city
- Make Point a value type (so that an independent copy is made
- Make Point an immutable type and change `Move` to return a *new* Point with the relevant change made

(Or some combination of the above...)

It sounds to me like Point should *probably* be a value type (a struct). Note that structs should almost *always* be immutable.

It seems somewhat odd to have a `newCity` instance method in the first place - what relation is the new city meant to have to the old city? Why aren't you just creating a completely separate city?

Comment: I shouldn't be surprised that the best advice came from Jon Skeet :) I concur that the Point should be immutable.

Comment: well, its a given API, so I cannot change it :(
the reason for this is so that this newCity method will create a new City based on a given one with the changes of CityName and the CityCenter will be moved according to dX,dY

Comment: @user344246: How much can't you change? It's clearly broken at the moment... Given that the number of neighbourhoods and number of residents is set as well, just how much does it have in common with the original? Just the central station?

Comment: I just need the Central Station x,y to create the new city based on those

Comment: Guys! Thank you very much. I got the problem...you've been very helpful :)

Comment: @user344246: It's not terribly clear from "newCity" that it really means "just preserve the location of the central station". Why not just have a City constructor which takes a central station to start with?